# Rails PayPal IPN activemerchant controller rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paypal-ipn, activemerchant

I have a PayPal API implemented in my system using activemerchant gem, i want to write some specs to test it, i have searched alot for an example but i didn't find any, i want to fully test the create action with a fake PayPal message, i tried this :

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Paypal::Notification.any_instance.stub('acknowledge').and_return(true)
```

But then the test entered an infinite loop and returned this error :

```
 Api::PaypalIpnController GET create update the order from pending to complete
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
```

I searched the internet many times but i didn't find an example or a reference on how to mock the PayPal message, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, the only mistake that i did is that i didn't stub the method using symbol naming, i mistakenly used this:

```
  any_instance.stub('acknowledge')
```

instead of this:

```
  any_instance.stub(:acknowledge)
```

I also wrote an example of [how to test IPN in Rspec](http://activemerchant-paypal-ipn-rspec-ror.blogspot.com/)